# Assign value to variable from Android Volley

Tags: android, json

**This is the code I wrote:**

```
public class ResultsFragment extends Fragment implements RequestHandler {
    FragmentNameFactory nameFactory = new FragmentNameFactory();
    String status = "1" ;
    public ResultsFragment(){
        //Fragment needs a constructor, can be empty
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).setFragmentName(nameFactory.getNameNL(5));
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fresults, container, false);
        RequestQueue rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        String url= "http://grwn.ddns.net:1337/results";
        final String body = "{\"id\":1}";
        RequestHandler requestHandler = this;
        VolleyStringRequest volleyStringRequest = new VolleyStringRequest(url, body, requestHandler);
        rq.add(volleyStringRequest.createStringRequest());
        Log.e("CreateView status", status);
        return view;
    }
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstance){
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstance);
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstance){
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstance);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        try{
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
            JSONArray values= jsonObject.getJSONArray("response");
            Log.e("RESPONSE", values.toString());
            Log.e("STATUS", jsonObject.get("status").toString());
            setStatus(jsonObject.get("status").toString());
            Log.e("status variable", status);
        }
        catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void setStatus(String value){
        status += value;
        Log.e("setStatus", status);
    }
}
```

**Interface:**

```
public interface RequestHandler {
    void onResponse(String response);
}
```

**VolleyClass:**

```
public class VolleyStringRequest {
    String url;
    String body;
    String value;
    RequestHandler requestHandler;
    public VolleyStringRequest(String url, String body, RequestHandler requestHandler){
        this.url = url;
        this.body = body;
        this.requestHandler = requestHandler;
        value= "";
    }
    public StringRequest createStringRequest(){
        return new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        // Do something with the response
                        Log.e("Response", response);
                        try{
                            JSONObject o = new JSONObject(response);
                            JSONArray values=o.getJSONArray("response");
                            value += o;
                            if(requestHandler != null){
                                requestHandler.onResponse(value);
                            }
                        }  catch (JSONException ex){}

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        // Handle error
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
                return body.getBytes();
            };
            @Override
            public String getBodyContentType() {
                return "application/json";
            }
        };

    }
}
```

I want to assign a object from the response to a global variable inside `ResultsFragment` and use it inside `onCreateView` but somehow I can't assign the value to the variable inside `onCreateView`. Later during run-time the value is assigned to the status variable. Could anyone help me fixing this?

Comment: "I want to assign a object from the response to a global variable inside ResultsFragment and use it inside onCreateView"
You can't do that, of course, since you're making a network request that will not complete for some indeterminate amount of time. So what are you actually trying to accomplish that you think you need this variable in onCreateView?

Comment: @dominicoder I want to check what the status is and based on that continue in the code

Answer (score 0):

Very generally speaking, in `onCreateView` you would show a progress spinner or something in your layout, then in your `onResponse` handler, you'd update your layout and set your variables, etc, based on the data you obtained from the request response.

So instead of requiring the data in `onCreateView` you'd defer until the response comes back and deal with it then.